# how can i find the number of business days between two of my date columns in bigquery?

Tags: sql, datetime, count, google-bigquery, subquery

this may seem simple but i can't find a solution to this online (without using functions).. i am using bigquery and want to find the number of business days between two days .

```
df['business_days'] = np.busday_count(date1,
                                     date2)
df['number_weekenddays'] = np.busday_count(date1,
                                      date2,
                                      weekmask='Sat Sun')
```

i am trying to replicate the above query in python into bigquery syntax. how can i do this? i have tried:

```
select
  order_date,
  pickup_date,
  case 
    when date_diff(pickup_date, order_date, week) > 0 
      then date_diff(pickup_date, order_date, day) - (date_diff(pickup_date, order_date, week) * 2)
    else
      date_diff(pickup_date, order_date, day) 
  end
from `orders.table`
```

But I get the following error:

> No matching signature for function DATE_DIFF for argument types: DATETIME, DATETIME, DATE_TIME_PART. Supported signature: DATE_DIFF(DATE, DATE, DATE_TIME_PART) at [186:10] Learn More about BigQuery SQL Functions.

even though the date column in question is a date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the simplest approach is to enumerate the days between the two dates, and filter out non-business days. `generate_date_array()` comes habdy for this:

```
select o.order_date, o.pickup_date, 
    (
        select count(*)
        from unnest(generate_date_array(date(o.order_date), date(o.pickup_date))) dt
        where dateofweek(dt) between 2 and 6
    ) cnt_business_days
from `orders.table` o
```

Comment: so if i want the number of weekends it would be 1 and 7?

Comment: @Maths12: if you wanted the count of weekend days, you would change `dateofweek(dt) between 2 and 6` with `dateofweek(dt) in (1, 7)`

Comment: thank you, do you also know how i can convert a my date column into seconds?

Comment: @Maths12: I don't see how this relates to your original question... But you can use [`unix_seconds()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#unix_seconds) for example

Answer (score 3):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select order_date, pickup_date,
  (select count(1) from all_days.day 
    where not extract(dayofweek from day) in (1, 7)
  ) as number_of_business_days
from `orders.table` t, 
unnest([struct(generate_date_array(order_date, pickup_date) as day)]) all_days
```

if to run for some dummy data  - output as below

[image]